# Comparing fields and keeping latest date with one table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Afternoon,

I am working with a set of records that lists credit card transactions that are appended to a default project code.  The first step is to import the records that populates the tblMaster.  The second step, 30 days later, is to append the next set of records to the tblMaster.  If the record has been moved to a project code, then it will not be in this record set.  If the record has NOT been moved to a project code it remains on the default project code list, which means you end up with two records and the only thing that is not the same between them is the report date which is equal to the date the report was run and the new records are appended to tblMaster.

Fields that I would like to line up to ensure we have the same record are the empName(Employee Name)
amount
item date
refNum (transaction reference number)
report Date

What I am having an issue with is the logic that says if the empName, amount, item date, refNum are all the same, then keep the later of the two report dates.  I want to get rid of the earlier report date by marking a Boolean box called matchRec as true.  This will filter out the record in my record set but I can still refer to it for historical purposes.

Here is what I have figured out so far as code:

```
 Dim db  As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

    Dim criteria As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblMaster Where matchRec = False Order By ID")
        Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblMaster Where matchRec= False Order By ID")


    Debug.Print

    While Not rs1.EOF
        criteria = _
            "empName = '" & rs1!empName.Value & "' And " & _
            "Quantity = " & Str(-rs1!Quantity.Value) & " And " & _
            "reportDate = '" & rs1!reportDate.Value & "' And " & _
            "matchRec = False"
        rs2.FindFirst criteria
        If rs2![reportDate] = rs1![reportDate] Then
                rs1!matchRec.Value = True
            rs1.Update
            rs2.Edit
                rs2!matchRec.Value = True
            rs2.Update
        End If
        rs1.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs2.Close
    rs1.Close

    Set rs2 = Nothing
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: i don't think you need code to do this, it should be doable with plain sql. you can mark the column you want to delete with an update statement and a subquery, and then run a delete statement that references that column to delete. there is more than way, but it should all be doable with just sql/queries

Comment: I don't want to delete the other record.  I just want to mark it with the boolean box.  Therefore I have a history of the transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is a query like this. I suspect your [RefNum] is unique, so you probably don't need any more joins, but I could be mistaken. if [refNum] alone does not uniquely identify a row, then add the remaining columns as needed to the join

```
UPDATE tblMaster a
Set matchRec = True
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM tblMaster b
WHERE a.refNum = b.refNum
     and b.ReportDate > a.ReportDate
)
```

Comment: O. Gungor - your idea was correct.  Except we modified the approach to only bring in the records to the db where there were no refNums.  So based on your idea, created an append query.  I used the ref number and created a right join on tblTemp showing the records in the tblMaster and tblTemp.  I then used a count function on the tblTemp.refNum to return the records where the count is null.  When the count is null, import those records.  I then run another routine to match values and set my Boolean values.  Great work and thanks for your help!